# update each record separately (php-mysql)

Tags: mysql, record, updating

Hi I have problem updating table(basic1) in the Mysql database I want to update each record separately (set all_cost_lend column with value new_cost_lend(all_cost_lend-min_mounth_lend)) but when I execute the code it gives me the records duplicate more than one time please help me to solve this problem.
This is the code

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
if(isset($_POST['xxx'])and $_POST['xxx']=='admin')
{
$data=mysql_query("select * from salafea order by id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
$new_cost_lend=$row['all_cost_lend']-$row['min_mounth_lend'];
$xy=mysql_query("update  salafea set all_cost_lend='$new_cost_lend'")or die  (mysql_error());
if(isset($xy)){
echo"<h1>update done! </h1>";
}
$data1=mysql_query("select * from salafea order by id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($data1)){
echo"<table bgcolor='abd9f9'width='79%'border='4'bordercolor='#7ACB83'>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>id</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:emp Name</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:File No</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>date_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>name_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>all_cost_lend:</td> 
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>before_cash_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>min_mounth_lend:</td>";
echo"<tr>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['id']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['emp_name']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['no_file']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['date_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['name_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['all_cost_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['before_cash_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['min_mounth_lend']."</td>";
}
}
echo"</table>";
}
else
{
echo "<form action='".$server['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value=' Please Press this button'>
<input type='hidden' name='id'/>
<input type='hidden' name='xxx' value='admin'/>
</form>";
$data=mysql_query("select * from salafea order by id") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<table bgcolor='abd9f9'width='79%'border='4'bordercolor='#7ACB83'>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>id</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:emp Name</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:File No</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>date_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>name_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>all_cost_lend:</td> 
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>before_cash_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>min_mounth_lend:</td>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
echo"<tr>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['id']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['emp_name']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['no_file']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['date_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['name_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['all_cost_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['before_cash_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['min_mounth_lend']."</td>";
}
echo"</table>";
}
?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause to tell it which rows to update.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have added a while loop in a while loop in 1st if condition if(isset($_POST['xxx']).That's why you are getting duplicate records.See updated code below

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
if(isset($_POST['xxx'])and $_POST['xxx']=='admin')
{

$new_cost_lend=$row['all_cost_lend']-$row['min_mounth_lend'];
$xy=mysql_query("update  salafea set all_cost_lend='$new_cost_lend'")or die  (mysql_error());
if(isset($xy)){
echo"<h1>update done! </h1>";
}

$data1=mysql_query("select * from salafea order by id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($data1)){
echo"<table bgcolor='abd9f9'width='79%'border='4'bordercolor='#7ACB83'>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>id</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:emp Name</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:File No</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>date_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>name_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>all_cost_lend:</td> 
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>before_cash_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>min_mounth_lend:</td>";
echo"<tr>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['id']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['emp_name']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['no_file']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['date_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['name_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['all_cost_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['before_cash_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row1['min_mounth_lend']."</td>";
}

echo"</table>";
}
else
{
echo "<form action='".$server['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value=' Please Press this button'>
<input type='hidden' name='id'/>
<input type='hidden' name='xxx' value='admin'/>
</form>";
$data=mysql_query("select * from salafea order by id") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<table bgcolor='abd9f9'width='79%'border='4'bordercolor='#7ACB83'>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>id</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:emp Name</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>:File No</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>date_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>name_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>all_cost_lend:</td> 
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>before_cash_lend:</td>
<td bgcolor='#7ACB83'>min_mounth_lend:</td>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
echo"<tr>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['id']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['emp_name']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['no_file']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['date_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['name_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['all_cost_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['before_cash_lend']."</td>
<td bgcolor='abd9f9'>".$row['min_mounth_lend']."</td>";
}
echo"</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I want to update all records in the table(separately) & if I put where id=number then I will update one record only

Comment: can you please explain "when you execute the code it gives records duplicate more than one time"? all records are updated?

Comment: I have three records with id(6-7-8) when I press the button it gives me  three record(6,7,8) with first id(6) value($new_cost_lend) & the three record again with id (7)value($new_cost_lend) & the last time also three record with id (8) value($new_cost_lend)

Comment: Thank you your answer help me to solve the problem but I edit your above code remove the line ($new_cost_lend=$row['all_cost_lend']-$row['min_mounth_lend'];) because I haven't mysql query to execute the above code ($row) not working also replace this line                               update  salafea set all_cost_lend='$new_cost_lend'              with this line                                                    update salafea set all_cost_lend=all_cost_lend-min_mounth_lend                                                     Thank you very much for your answer